# Good practice to define print() for R6 in R?

Tags: r, r6

I want to modify print() for my R6 class so that if field `dt` is still NULL, it print the entire Class information, as done by default. However, when dt is NOT NULL, then it only prints dt, like in example below.
How to do that?

```
library(R6)
Simple <- R6Class(
  "Simple", 
  portable = F, # for convenience so that I can use either dt or self$dt in class functions
  public = list(
    x=1, y=2, 
    dt = NULL,
    print = function (...) {
      if (is.null(dt)){
        print(...)
      } else {
        print(self$dt)
      }
    },
    date="2020-10-10"
  )
)
s <- Simple$new()
s
# I WANT THIS TO BE PRINTEED
# <Simple>
#   Public:
#   clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#     date: 2020-10-10
#     dt: NULL
#     x: 1
#     y: 2
s$dt <- mtcars
s
# WILL PRINT mtcars
```

Comment: I haven't used R6 before, but it seems inconsistent in your code that you have `self$dt` in one place and just `dt` in another. (Within the `print` method.)

Comment: corrected that in my question - I used portable = FALSE (so I can use both dt and self$dt. I found it convenient in most cases, so you are not afraid to incidently call dt from your parent environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `s` into the console, you invoke the (S3) generic `print` function, which dispatches `R6:::print.R6`. If you look at what `R6:::print.R6` does, it searches for a member function of the object called "print", and if it is present, it uses that to print the object.

If a `print` method has not been defined for the R6 object, then `R6:::print.R6` will use `R6:::format.R6` to display the R6 object. This is what you want to see when `dt` is `NULL`.

You will need to do the same within your `print` method, since the act of defining a `print` method within your class prevents this behaviour.

Fortunately, this is straightforward:

```r
library(R6)

Simple <- R6Class(
  "Simple",
  public = list(
    x = 1, y = 2, 
    dt = NULL,
    print = function (...) {
      if (is.null(self$dt)){
        cat(format(self, ...), sep = "\n")
      } else {
        print(self$dt)
      }
    },
    date="2020-10-10"
  )
)

s <- Simple$new()
s
#> <Simple>
#>   Public:
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     date: 2020-10-10
#>     dt: NULL
#>     print: function (...) 
#>     x: 1
#>     y: 2

s$dt <- 'Dt content only'
s
#> [1] "Dt content only"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Excellent explanation and solution! It also exposed a problem with my (edited) code when I use portable = F.      If I keep it as portable = F, then your solution WILL NOT WORK, because when I write 'print()' it refers to self$print()'  giving this error: `"Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`. So I do need to make it portable = T in order for your solution to work!

Comment: And if anyone still wants to keep class as  `portable = F` (which I often do - for convenience), than one has to write explicitly `base::print(dt)` instead of `print(self$dt)` and it will work!